# Making all image clips the same size in MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy

All of the images in the final clip come out as static except for the first one.

```
from assigning import images, text
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize

clips = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip(f"Audio/{i}.mp3")
    image_clip = ImageClip(images[i])
    video_clip = image_clip.set_audio(audio_clip).set_duration(audio_clip.duration)
    video_clip.resize((1920,1080))
    clips.append(video_clip)

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
final_clip.resize((1920,1080))
final_clip.write_videofile("output.mp4", fps=60, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac', temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True)
```

I believe that the resolutions and/or the sizes of the images are different, which is causing the problem. How do I fix this?